# How to replace .c and .cpp file together?

Tags: makefile

I am currently have an Android.mk file. For some requirement I need to write a standard GNU make file to build the same program.

As you know in Android native build, we simply put all source files together like

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := a.c b.c d.cpp e.cpp
```

Now I want to do something in Makefile like:

```
OBJ = $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES: .c=.o)
```

This will only transform .c files with .o object targets. How can I combine the condition **".c or .cpp"** together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use basename:

```
OBJ := $(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES)))
```

(strips off the suffix of each file in `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` then adds `.o` to the end)

Answer (score 7):

I think I am too busy to forget that I can just achieve this target by execute this function twice.

```
TMP_OBJ = $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES: .c=.o)
OBJ = $(TMP_OBJ: .cpp=.o)
```

Sorry for this silly question.

Answer (score 2):

Doing it in two steps:

```
SRC := main.c hello.cpp
OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)
OBJ := $(OBJ:.cpp=.o)
```